# .Net 3.5 DLL XML dependency

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5, deployment, configuration

I wrote a class library in C# that uses a external XML file to store some data. I use this data (encoded rules) directly in the class library to do some substitutions within a text parser. The rules within the XML:

```
 <rule>
   <word>h e l l o</word>
   <sub>Hello</sub>
 </rule>
```

When I share the lib, I also have to share the XML. This is a bug source, at least for me ;) My question: is there any common way to solve such issues? Should I use app.config instead?

Thanks for any hint and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with every external configuration data i can be changed or missing. So your application (or library) has to deal with such circumstances.

This means:

- For every missing value you have a default value (should be declared in your documentation)
- Check every value for correctness (type, range, etc.) (All input is evil!)
- Blame user for invalid config files (error message, etc)
- Implement and document behaviour in error case (abort, crash, use default value, etc)

So it doesn't matter which way to go, cause it is a user configuration (which means it can be changed by the user) and so you have to check those entries.

Comment: Ok, I will consider all these hints! I thought there are some common convetions I did'nt heard about.

Answer (score 1):

Why not embed the XML within the dll?

Comment: Yeap.. you could add it as a resource to the solution and in the properties select embedded.

Comment: Because the xml could be changed by the user after deployment. New rules can be added or old ones needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Create the XML file with default settings/values if it doesn´t exist.

Comment: This will help to avoid a FileNotFound exception, yes. I will validate the XML via XSD too.